# Refreshing a deleted question

Tags: bug, ios-app

If question was deleted during manual refreshing iOS app shows this text:

> [image: deleted]

Tapping on the "Open in Chrome" link opens incorrect URL:

> [image: chrome]

- App Version: 1.6.2.5
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.2 (Build 14C92)

Comment: Already fixed :)

Comment: @Cai do you have 1.6.3? I made subscription for beta, but never had a link for it yet.

Comment: I have it. Brian probably forgot to add you, ping him somewhere and remind him

Comment: @Cai Hmm... I thought it works automatically. Space technology :)